# sdn - mininet openflow tutorial

Tags: sdn, mininet, openflow

I am new to mininet and trying to follow the tutorial on mininet/openflow https://github.com/mininet/openflow-tutorial/wiki/Learn-Development-Tools

I have a problem with the Wireshark. Here in the tutorial it is said that:

> open Wireshark:
>
> *>  $ sudo wireshark*
>
> Now, set up a filter for OpenFlow control traffic, by typing 'of' in
>   Filter box near the top:
>   Press the apply button to apply the filter to all recorded traffic.

I did this, but I encounter this error:

```
"of" isn't a valid display filter: "of" is neither a field nor a protocol name.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out openflow packets just type `openflow` instead `of` or you can generate expression by choosing from the window that gets popped up when you click on expression button